# Passing class reference to another class not working

Tags: c#, winforms, class, inheritance

I have a fairly complicated application, so I decided to organize code a bit and am having problems with references to the main class not working anymore. I already had a structure with classes, but all of them were properties of the main class and had no other class properties that would need the reference to the main class.

So my structure was like this: `Main Class -> Class1, Class2, Class3 etc.`

After restructuring I created a structure similar to this:

```
Main Class -> (Class1 -> Class12, Class13), Class2, Class3 etc.
```

I was passing the reference to the main class just fine to all of them before, but now that I have a deeper structure, I am getting the main `class null` error.

The structure relevant to this particular error is this:

```
MainWindow: Form -> MaxFlow (algorithm) -> LabelNodes (a part of that algorithm)
```

The structure is fairly simple since most of my code is completely irrelevant to the problem.

First I have the `MainWindow` class.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form {
    private MaxFlow maxFlow; // Algorithm
    internal MaxFlow MaxFlow { get => maxFlow; set => maxFlow = value; }

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

    maxFlow = new MaxFlow(mainWindow: this);
    }
```

Then the `Maxflow` class:

```
class MaxFlow {
    private MainWindow mainWindow;

    public MaxFlow(MainWindow mainWindow) {
        mainWindow = this.mainWindow;
    }
```

and then the last class with nodes:

```
class LabelNodes {
    private MainWindow mainWindow;

    public LabelNodes(MainWindow mainWindow) {
        this.mainWindow = mainWindow;
    }

    public AddNewNodeLabel() { 
        //…

        // THIS PART THROWS THE ERROR (mainWindow equal to null):
        Label newLabel = new Label  {
            Location = mainWindow.LastClickLocation,
            Name = ”…”
        };

    //…
    }
```

I tried setting breakpoints and found out that the reference to the `MainWindow` class is `null` already before passing it to the `LabelNodes` class, it gets passed as `null` in the `MaxFlow` class.

Since I had no problems before transferring the `LabelNodes` class from `MainWindow` to `MaxFlow`, I suspect the problem is because I am passing it two times but do not understand why this could be a problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems line you got the dependencies in the wrong direction. MaxFlow should know nothing of the main window. On the contrary, the window should bind to MaxFlow.

Comment: A nice improvement to you structure would be: You could pass the `mainWindow.LastClickLocation` as parameter to the `AddNewNodeLabel()` method. This way you don't need to pass the MainWindow as parameter. This will also break the dependency on the `mainWindow` class, which is much nicer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is not correct: You should assign the `this.mainWindow` instead of the parameter mainWindow. It will assign the default value null in the field to the parameter.  *(in the Maxflow class)*

```
class MaxFlow {
   private MainWindow mainWindow;

   public MaxFlow(MainWindow mainWindow) {
       // mainWindow = this.mainWindow;   <-----
       // should be:
       this.mainWindow = mainWindow;
   }
```

---

Like DavidG pointed out. Better naming convension would prevent making these mistakes:

```
class MaxFlow 
{
   private MainWindow _mainWindow;

   public MaxFlow(MainWindow mainWindow) 
   {
       _mainWindow = mainWindow;
   } 
}
```

Comment: A good argument for better variable naming too, common convention is to prefix private variables with an underscore.

Comment: @DavidG Yep!, I'm using the `_` for my private fields also. It's clear and readable. Works like a charm.

Comment: How stupid of me :D Thank you for such quick help and the tip with the naming convention!